# add value of one key and value to another property in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    education: [{
      degree: 'bachelors',
      Major: 'computers'
    }, {
      degree: 'masters',
      Major: 'computers'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Alice',
    education: [{
      degree: 'bachelors',
      Major: 'electronics'
    }, {
      degree: 'masters',
      Major: 'electronics'
    }]
  }
];


const resultArray = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    education: [{
      degree: 'bachelors',
      Major: 'computers',
      id: 1
    }, {
      degree: 'masters',
      Major: 'computers',
      id: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Alice',
    education: [{
      degree: 'bachelors',
      Major: 'electronics',
      id: 2
    }, {
      degree: 'masters',
      Major: 'electronics',
      id: 2
    }]
  }
];
```

I am looking to add the `id` and its value of array to the `education` array objects. Can you suggest me how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: are the added id, id of the person or per major ?

Comment: its id of the person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop over to the `array` to get each object inside `array` and then add `id` value to the `education` array by looping through the `education` array. You can use a simple `for` loop or `Array.forEach()` as changing any object property in a object will reflect the original object.

**USING `forEach()`**

```js
const array = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Bob',
  education: [{
    degree: 'bachelors',
    Major: 'computers'
  }, {
    degree: 'masters',
    Major: 'computers'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Alice',
  education: [{
    degree: 'bachelors',
    Major: 'electronics'
  }, {
    degree: 'masters',
    Major: 'electronics'
  }]
}];
array.forEach((item) => {
  item.education.forEach((educationObj) => {
    educationObj['id'] = item.id;
  });
});
console.log(array);
```

**USING `for`**

```js
const array = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Bob',
  education: [{
    degree: 'bachelors',
    Major: 'computers'
  }, {
    degree: 'masters',
    Major: 'computers'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Alice',
  education: [{
    degree: 'bachelors',
    Major: 'electronics'
  }, {
    degree: 'masters',
    Major: 'electronics'
  }]
}];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
 for(var j=0; j<array[i].education.length; j++){
    array[i].education[j]['id'] = array[i].id;
  }
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you just need a nested **[`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** call to perform this:

```
const resultArray = array.map(x => {
  x.education = x.education.map(e => {
    e.id = x.id;
    return e;
  });
  return x
});
```

The first `.map()` call is to loop and transform your original `array` 
and the second inner `.map()` is to update and transform inner `education` array.

**Demo:**

```js
const array = 
      [{ id: 1, name: 'Bob', education: [{degree: 'bachelors', Major: 'computers'}, {degree: 'masters', Major: 'computers'}] },
       { id: 2, name: 'Alice', education: [{degree: 'bachelors', Major: 'electronics'}, {degree: 'masters', Major: 'electronics'}] }];

const resultArray = array.map(x => {
  x.education = x.education.map(e => {
    e.id = x.id;
    return e;
  });
  return x
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use nested maps to solve it.

```
const resultArray = array.map((arr) => {
  array.education = arr.education.map((e) => {
   e.id = arr.id;
   return e;
 });
 return arr;
});
```

Comment: Downvote for a very clear case of copy/paste. Shame on you.

Comment: It may feel as copy paste but i dint copy paste. By the time i posted the answer already someone had posted with the same answer.